# The system cannot contact a domain controller to service the authentication

Tags: windows-server-2012

help me, When the user logs in and user tries to access them mapped drives user gets the error stating "The system cannot contact a domain controller to service the authentication request" . i can ping  the domain controller by name, domain name, FQDN, or ip address. On these computers you can still use the internet but it connects to either "Network" rather than our domain and won't let you access drives

Comment: Is this for all computers on the network or for only specific ones? Have you confirmed DNS settings are correct on the workstation (it is set to the IP address of the domain controller) and that the domain controller does not have a firewall blocking connections?

Comment: all computer. yes i set to the IP address of the domain controller in dns